# How to get data from DB in Test Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-5.5

Hello I write test and want to get data from DB in it, so I do next

**Company.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'companies';
}
```

**MyTest.php**

```
<?php
use App\Models\Company;

class MyTest extends TestCase {

    public function testFileUploadAction()
    {
        $company = Company::find(1);
    }


}
```

but have error

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function connection() on a non-object
>   in
>   /myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 3146

So how I can get data From DB in test?

**Update:**
all my tests work fine issue only in get data from DB in test.

**Model** work fine.

****Update**
I found solution
error was because application wasn't booted so I add

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();
```

and all work fine

Comment: Please add routes.php and your App\Models\Company object

Comment: routes.php? what it will show you?

Comment: The line that refers to your MyTestController. I actually ope that TestCase class is extending BaseController tat comes with laravel is it?

Comment: I do like this http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing#defining-and-running-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution error was because application wasn't booted so I add

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();
```

and all work fine